# How to best design a database in Access when two fields have the same values lists?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2016

I have created a table in Access 2016 with two fields: current salary (range A, e.g. 20 000 - 29 000, 30 000 - 39 000 etc.), expected range after graduation (range B, e.g. 20 000 - 29 000, 30 000 - 39 000 etc.). The range list for A and B is the same and I used the same table C as a source for both.

The problem comes when I create a query, where I want to specify a certain range in Range A and AT THE SAME TIME in Range B. E.g. People, who are having a current salary in 20 000 - 29 000 range AND are looking for a salary in 30 000 - 39 000 range.

The results are obviously invalid (less result, than expected).

Could you explain,
1. Why does this problem appear in the frist place? (I suppose the reason is the same values list for two fields, but why is this a problem?)
2. Is there another way to fix it besides having two different "Range sources" tables for Range A and B?

Comment: The immediate answer is to bring table C into the query twice - once with a join to CurrentSalary and once with join to ExpectedSalary.  As you suggested, the other choice is 2 separate tables, which would also give you flexibility if you ever decide to have different range tables for the 2 fields.

Comment: I'm not following why this isn't working. Can you provide the SQL you wrote to get the invalid results?